# share function in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, share

In android, the share function is using `MIME` type.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        Config_ConstantVariable.sharelink + newsid);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                        "Share via"));
```

How about in Blackberry RIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Send Menu API in BlackBerry Java SDK 7.0 which provides similar functionality but although not feature rich .The official documentation says the following about the Send Menu API.

> You can use the Send Menu API to add a Send menu item to a menu in your app. The Send menu item allows you to send content from your app to a recipient by using another application on the BlackBerry device, such as the Messages application or BlackBerry Messenger. The content to send is encapsulated in a JSONObject object that is passed from your app to the application that sends the content from the device.
>
> When a BlackBerry device user clicks the Send menu item, a submenu is displayed with a list of applications that can be used to send the content. When the user clicks one of these applications, the selected application starts with certain fields populated automatically with the content to send. The user can complete the remaining fields and send the content.

Comment: can you provide an example? I am confusing. Moreover, I am develop RIM 5.0 so must use the function that support 5.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no such API. You could use Invocation API to send message over sms, email. But there are no public API to share content with third part app like FB or Twitter. You could do it yourself by using FB SDK or implementing Twitter API yourself.